# Creación de Dispositivo inteligente en simulador

Tags: c++, arduino

soy nuevo por aquí y tengo un proyecto de fin de curso, se nos ah encargado crear un dispositivo con un simulador, el simulador es proteus 8.11 y tinkercad

El programa dice lo siguiente:

> Crear un dispositivo inteligente de seguridad el cual tendra un sensor de movimiento. El dispositivo contara con un switch de deslizamiento para el encendido y apagado, al encenderlo tendra un lapso de 3 segundos (simulados por un contador) para alejarse y que la alarma no detecte al usuario, el dispositivo contara con un teclado matricial similar a un sistema de alarma que sera utilizado para desactivar el encendido de la alrma mediante una clave, cada alumno usara su fecha de nacimiento iniciando por mes luego dia solamente en 4 dijitos, si la clave de desactivacion no se hace antes de 3 segundos sonara la alarma mediante un sonar piezoelectrico.
>
> La alarma se desactivara con una clave de dos digitos opcional y reiniciara el sistema donde si el switch ya esta apagado no se repetira nevamente la accion de loc ontrario se repetira nuevamente todo.
>
> Parte analoga: Conectar un led a la salida de un pin digital PWM y enviar los valores requeridos para variar el ancho de pulso desde Labview mediante un slide y observar que ocurre a la salida con el led

El problema es que al momento de ejecutar mi código, no realiza lo que se pide, en el monitor no detecta las teclas seleccionadas y en si no funciona.

Código:

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#define sw 12
#define led 6
#define led2 A0
#define sensor 7
#define buzzer 13
float s;
const byte FILAS = 4;     
const byte COLUMNAS = 4;   
char keys[FILAS][COLUMNAS] = {  
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte pinesFilas[FILAS] = {11,10,9,8};  
byte pinesColumnas[COLUMNAS] = {5,4,3,2};

Keypad teclado = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), pinesFilas, pinesColumnas, FILAS, COLUMNAS);

char TECLA; //almacena la tecla seleccionada      
char CLAVE[5];  //array que guarda  las teclas      
char CLAVE_MAESTRA[5] = "0812"; //clave de desactivacion
byte INDICE = 0; //lee la teclas


//segunda clave para apagar el buzzer
char CLAVE2[3];        
char CLAVE_MAESTRA2[3] = "11";
char TECLA2;
byte INDICE2 = 0; 



void setup() 
{
    
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(sw, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
    
    
}
void loop() 
{
 
  
  
    int mod = digitalRead(sw);
    int mods = digitalRead(sensor);
      

    if(mod)//si el switch esta encendido, el dispositivo esta encendido
      {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
            delay(3000);  
  
      
     //lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
                 if(mods==HIGH)//si el sensor se activa
                 {
        
       
      /////////////////////////////////////   
                    int t;
                    t=t+1;
                    t++; //contador de segundos
        
        
                   TECLA = teclado.getKey(); //objeto del teclado
                   if (TECLA)        
                    {
                       CLAVE[INDICE] = TECLA;   
                       INDICE++;    
                       Serial.print(TECLA);  //insertar la primera clave
                    } 
        
        
                  if(INDICE == 4 && t<=3000) //si la clave tiene los 4 dijitos y el tiempo es menor a los segundos limitados
                  {
    
                       if(!strcmp(CLAVE, CLAVE_MAESTRA))//comprueba si la clav es correcta
                       {
                             Serial.println(" Correcta");  
                             digitalWrite(led, HIGH); //la clave es correcta y se activa un led
                       }
                      else //de lo contrario, la clave es incorrecta y los segundos superiores al limite y se activa el buzzer
                      {
                            Serial.println(" Incorrecta"); 
                            digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
                            TECLA = teclado.getKey();
                            if (TECLA)  //se solicita la segunda clave para desactivar el buzzer
                                  {
                                       CLAVE2[INDICE2] = TECLA2;   
                                       INDICE++;    
                                       Serial.print(TECLA2);    
                                   } 
                             if(!strcmp(CLAVE2, CLAVE_MAESTRA2))//compara si la clave es correcta
                              {
                                        Serial.println(" Correcta");  
                                        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW); //la clave es correcta y se apaga el buzzer
                              }
                        INDICE2=0; 
                      }

                  INDICE = 0;
                 }  

      /////////////////////////////
        }
        
    
   //llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
      }
  
    else //si el switch esta apagado, el dispositivo esta apagado
      {
            digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
      }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Cómo crees que podemos ayudarte a partir de un enunciado y "nos marca distintos errores"? Si compartes lo que han hecho Y LOS ERRORES, ojalá todo como texto, tal vez tengamos alguna oportunidad de comentar algo. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Ok ok, estoy en eso

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error aquí:

```
if (mods == HIGH) //si el sensor se activa
{
  int t;
  t = t + 1;
  t++; //contador de segundos
```

La variable `t` se crea dentro del `if` con valor cero; luego le sumas 1 y enseguida le aplicas autoincremento.

El resultado final es que `t`, el contador de segundos es siempre 2.

Luego de terminar el `if`, la variable desaparece, sólo para ser recreada en la próxima pasada por `loop`, quedando de nuevo con valor 2.

La declaración de `t` debería ser global al script o bien declarada `static` dentro de `loop`.

Comment: Si bien estás en lo correcto Moe, creo que el problema del usuario viene por otro lado, probablemente relacionado con asumir que el entero `t` representa tiempo dentro del loop o ese `delay` que bloquea las lecturas. Probablemente el `mods==high` debiera ser un `while` y chequear al final del bucle si pasa a `low`, acabándosele el tiempo para escribir la clave.

Comment: @MarceloZárate. Debe haber más de un problema, por cierto, pero soy un "compilador" simple: al primero error dejo de procesar.